# How do I use NFC tag, to unlock a PC, with my NFC enabled phone?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, login, remote-login, nfc

I am looking for a way to use my phone's NFC capabilities to be put in use for logging in to my laptop. The laptop does not have any NFC capability. So, I am looking for a workaround, that an NFC tag trigger the bluetooth in laptop when I touch my NFC phone to the tag, and lead me to log in to my laptop. I was hoping this community may help me.

Comment: I have Windows 10 on Lenovo notebook with NFC, and phone with NFC, also would like to have app to automatically unlock/sign-in to Windows 10. But I can not find the app that does that..

Answer (score 1):

Use phone sign in in windows 10 market.
You can stick NFC tag to your laptop and write command with some NFC write app in Google play. From an app like that you can define a command that will turn Bluetooth on.
Keep Bluetooth on on your laptop.

Just an idea, maybe there's a better way.

Comment: It is a nice idea, but the phone sign in works only on Windows Mobile. I have an Xperia. Anything for that?

Comment: There is Windows 10 feature (Dynamic lock) which works using Bluetooth proximity of your phone for lock/unlock, described here - https://forums.tomshardware.com/faq/how-to-use-your-phone-to-lock-and-unlock-windows-10.3148841/ , but it does not have nothing to do with this topic - NFC lock/unlock :)